# Priority Queue C

Tags: c, queue, linked-list

I'm trying to create a `priority queue` using an array of queues, each index of the array being a priority. I tried the following solution,

The queue data type contains an array llist,

```
Queue *q_create(int size)
{
struct queue *p;
struct q_head *h;
int i;

if ((p = (struct queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue))) != NULL) {
    p->size = size;
    for (i = 0; i < PRIODIFF; i++) {
        h = &(p->llist[i]);
        h->head = NULL;
        h->tail = NULL;
    }
}
return p;
}
```

I'm confused by the line: `h = &(p->llist[i]);`
I was thinking that `llist[i] = h`.
Is this another way of writing it in C? I'm reading it as `h = the address of llist[i]`.
Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I'm reading it as h = the address of llist[i] Is that correct?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should read that as assign the address of `p->llist[i]` to `h`.  This is not the same as `llist[i] = h`.

This code is using `h` as a short-hand to avoid having to type `p->llist[i]` twice for the two subsequent lines.